# Class Variable Updating

Tags: python

I built a class to handle a lot of different functions that take common inputs. However, I just ran into the situation where one of the variables that's fed down through `self` needs to be changed. How do I do this? This is an example:

```
class Test: 
    def __init__(self, test_variable):
        self.test_var = test_variable

    @property
    def some_function(self): 
        if self.test_var < 0:
           self.test_var = 'New Output'   #this is the line that I can't get 
                                          #get to work and I was hoping to update it here
                                          #so I could use it in later functions
        return self.test_var
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're encountering? The code you posted does exactly what you expect it to, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Note that if you want `self.test_var`, you call `self.some_function`.

Comment: Other than not being able to call `some_function` more than once is `test_variable` is initially negative, what is the problem?

Comment: Is `test_var` supposed to contain a string or a number? After you assign a string to it, comparing it with a number will cause an error.

Comment: It's a string that I would like to reassign as a string. Maybe I made it too simple to be an effective example. The error I was getting was "can't assign attribute" error.

Answer (score 1):

You should drop the `@property` attribute. Then, you can set it by just doing `x.test_var = 5`. E.g.,

```
class Test: 
    def __init__(self, test_variable):
        self.test_var = test_variable

    def some_function(self): 
        if self.test_var < 0:
           self.test_var = 'New Output'   #this is the line that I can't get 
                                          #get to work and I was hoping to update it here
                                          #so I could use it in later functions
        return self.test_var

x = Test(-1)

print(x.some_function())
x.test_var = 5
print(x.some_function())
```

returns

```
New Output
5
```

Comment: You have dropped the `@property` decorator from the method.  I think that might be where he/she was having issues.